How to show $\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ for $k>1$?
For a fixed constant $k>1$ which is not necessarily an integer, consider the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}.
$$
I want to show that $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0,1)$.
I tried to take derivative and got
$$
f^\prime(x)=\frac{(k-1)x^k-kx^{k-1}+1}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
But I still don't know how to show that the numerator is positive for all $0<x<1$ and for general $k>1$, although I tried some special values of $k$ and found that it is true.

For positive integer $k$ and $x \in (0,1)$ you have  $f(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{k-1}$ which is clearly positive

What if $k$ is not an integer?
